Does Adharma (embodiment of evil & Brahma's creation from his back) mentioned again, like Dharmadeva?
Dharmadeva (the embodiment of righteouness/good and mind-born son of Brahma) is appearing again in scriptures, especially in Mahabharata, other than his genealogy.
But? Does Adharma mentioned again, despite his genealogy, like Dharmadeva in scripture?

Could you show any source where Dharma shows up, other than genealogically?

Yeah, sure. According to Shanti Parva, Section CXCIX, Dharmadeva is appeared to a Brahmana , here the verse:- "Dharma said, 'O regenerate one, behold me who am Dharma. I have come here for seeing thee. Thou hast won the reward of this recitation in which thou hadst been engaged."

Adharma is Kali a.k.a Duryodhana.. foremost he is deity of adharma that is why this yuga is named after him, it was stated only sinful souls are born in this yuga.. apart very few poius soul
